# How to add an attribute (or change) to children elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this simple script to add the target="_blank" attribute to all the  elements.

```
$(function(){
$('a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

It is working great but I want only the `<a>` in the `<div id="main">` to be affected by this script.

I tried :

```
$('#main').$('a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

But this is just not working....

Comment: If you're looking for children specifically (not all descendants), use `$("#main > a")` or `$("#main").children("a")`

Answer (score 5):

Use this :

```
$('#main').find('a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#main a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

You should check out the jQuery website for information about selectors (the selector is the string passed to $ function).

In this case, jQuery will select all "a" tags within any tag with the id "main".

- '#' means 'id'
- '.' means 'css class'
- '>' means 'absolute children'
- And a lot more

You can even specify a tag with a css class. For example, if you'd like to only affect 'a' tags that have the css class 'blankLink', you could do this

```
$('#main a.blankLink').attr('target', '_blank');
```

Check [this](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) out!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a','#main').attr('target','_blank');
```

Should also work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the structure of your html is like this:

```
  <div id="main">
         <a id="1"></a>
         <a id="2"></a>
         <a id="3"></a>

         <div>
           <a id="4"></a>
            <div>
               <a id="5"></a>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

NOTE:

This will change 1,2,3,4,5:

```
 $('#main a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

This will change 1,2,3:

```
   $('#main > a').attr('target', '_blank');
```